# SQL Server 2008 collation

Tags: mysql, sql-server, unicode, utf-8

I am moving a table from MySQL to SQL Server 2008 which holds a mixture of characters in one e.g. english, Français, Ελλάδα

When I do this I either get the Greek character represented by ????? or I loose the French/Spanish accents?

I have set my columns up as `nvarchar` for unicode and played around with the collations but I cannot seem to figure this one out.

Comment: How are you transferring the data between the two systems? Linked server of some kind, or CSV files, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out my problem was with the actuall insert script I was running. You using NVarchar field you need add an "N" to the insert. i.e. myColumn = N'Ελλάδα'.

Comment: This is duplicate of my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106373/sql-server-2008-collation/4111782#4111782

Answer (score 1):

What SQL Commands are you using??

When inserting into MS SQL you need to use the COLLATE keyword for each column that has a special collation.

Comment: How would one exactly COLLATE for "a mixture of characters in one e.g. english, Français, Ελλάδα"?

Comment: I quess that depends on what "holds a mixture of characters in one" means - what is one in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that MySQL characters are correctly converted to ucs-2 (unicode) used by SQL Server from whatever collation/encoding you have in MySQL (probably, utf-8?)

See. for ex., [Insert UTF8 data into a SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379416/insert-utf8-data-into-a-ms-sql-server-2008)